# IntelliJ IDEA 12 code completion without capitalisation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In eclipse 4.2, I can just type:

```
joptionpane
```

and press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>** and it will turn into:

```
JOptionPane
```

Is there any way to do the same with intelliJ IDEA? I have tried pressing **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>**, and **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>**. But, for some reason it just does not work.

I would be most grateful if anyone could show me how to do this.

I am just trying out version 12 of IDEA, since some of my friends told me that it was a better IDE and had better code completion (their opinions).

Comment: I faced exactly same problem in Android Studio as well as it is also based on intelliJ platform only.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can disable the case sensitivity of the code completion in the settings menu:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code completion -> Case sensitive completion

[image]

If you then type "jo" and hit TAB, it will expand to JOptionPane.

## Updated screenshot for IntelliJ 15

[image]

## Update screenshot for IntelliJ 2018

[image]

Comment: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code completion -> Case sensitive completion in Intellij 14

Comment: Default should have been case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA is very senstive to capitalisation so I doubt it will ignore it.  You can type `JOP+<tab>` and it will give you JOptionPane.

Comment: Even `JO<tab>` is enough -- just tested :p