# Code completion to in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

A question about the editor, I am not sure how to **briefly** phrase the question so I could not find an answer

I have just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio on the Mac.

If in a layout file, I start typing android:au, assuming I want to choose autotext see screenshot
[image]

How can I get the completion to go upto the "to" of "auto". So that I just have to type the T and then enter to choose autoText.

Since there are no options without the "to" I should be allowed to select it.

Please let me know if my explanation is not clear enough

Comment: Related post - [IntelliJ IDEA 12 code completion without capitalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14127381/465053)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Intellij (Studio) parses the whole text to search for your input characters by default. If you type **"Text"**, it should show **"autoText"** in the options by default. You don't have to configure anything for this behavior.

It will give preference to exact matches though, so if you type in **"Text"** with a capital **T**, you're more likely to get the correct result than typing **"text"** with a small **t**.

You can change these preferences in:

`Settings(or Preferences in mac)->Editor->Code Completion`

Comment: In the version I'm running (2016.2.2), its under Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion.

Comment: For Android Studio 3, 'Case Sensitive Completion' option doesn't exist. Untick 'Match Case' checkbox will be the alternative solution.

Answer (score 49):

You can set 'Case sensitive completion' to 'None' in IDE Settings > Editor > Code Completion.

Comment: In Android Studio go for File > Settings >Editor > General >Code Completion and then select None for "Case Sensitive Completion"

Comment: Or in both IDEA and Android Studio just press Ctrl+Alt+S and type "case" to access this option :)

Answer (score 27):

in Android studio   open File----> Setting (Ctrl + Alt + S) you can use this shortcut

from Setting open Editor --->General --> Code Completion -- > change Case Sensitive Completion to **None**

look at image below

[image]

Comment: that was driving me nuts until I realized this has to be configurable. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

make sure to disable "power save mode" in your File >> Power save mode.