# Autocomplete ArrayList declaration

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea

Can IntelliJ Idea autocomplete my arraylist declaration if I 
entered typename with lower case?
When I type `ArrayL` starting with capital letter I'm getting autocompletetion instantly.

But if I start typing `arraylist` with lowercase I can not get autocompletetion in any way. I tried `ctrl-space`, `ctrl-shift-space` but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can check this answer. Not sure if it is exactly the same currently, since this link refers to version 12 and current is 15:

[IntelliJ IDEA 12 code completion without capitalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127381/intellij-idea-12-code-completion-without-capitalisation)

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer does include updated screenshots for version 15.

Comment: True. I didn't see that. I only saw the first screenshot and especially the explanation about how to go to that option.